# Regex: match single equal sign with negative lookahead =

Tags: php, regex

I am building something that requires the user to input conditions and then I will parse it with PHP. I want to build a preg_replace that replaces = with == but == remains untouched.

Examples

```
a=b => a==b
a==b => a==b
a = b => a == b
a == b => a == b
```

So basically if a user forgets that the condition needs == instead of =, the system will allow that too.

Comment: You could replace all the == with = and then replace all the = with ==.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use positive lookbehind to assert what is on the left is either a word character `\w` or a whitespace character `\s`

```
(?<=[\w\s])=+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gqaOFc/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/Om0kq)

For example:

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?<=[\w ])=+/', '==', $str)
```

Comment: This works ok but also replaces != with !==, I need != to remain !=

Comment: @Filip I have updated my answer using positive lookbehind.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex,

```
(?<![=!])=(?![=!])
```

Which ensures a `=` will only be selected if it is not preceded or followed by a `=` and replace it by `==`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tOregF/2)**

Sample PHP codes,

```
$arr = array("a=b", "a==b", "a = b", "a == b", "a!=b");
foreach($arr as $s) {
    echo $s, ' --> ', preg_replace('/(?<![=!])=(?![=!])/', '==', $s) , "\n";
}
```

Prints,

```
a=b --> a==b
a==b --> a==b
a = b --> a == b
a == b --> a == b
a!=b --> a!=b
```

Comment: It does not work ok though. "!=" is now replaced by "!=="

Comment: I didn't knew you wanted this behavior too. Let me update my regex for solving this case too. Also if you have any other similar case, please let me know so I can give you a working solution for all your cases.

Comment: @Filip: Updated my answer. Please check and also if you have any other constraints, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the desired result by doing the following :

```
$string = "a == b" ;
$string = str_replace('==', '=', $string);
$string = str_replace('=', '==', $string);

var_dump($string);
```

By replacing all `==` to `=` and then replacing all `=` to `==`